# Atribuir uma classe a outra em C++

Tags: c++, herança

Existe uma classe como abaixo:

```
class vetor
{
protected:
    int x, y;
public:
    //Construtor
    vetor(int _x=0, int _y=0);
};
```

e outra:

```
class pos : public vetor
{

public:
    //Construtor
    pos();

    umaFuncaoQualquer(int _x=0, int _y=0);
    outraFuncaoQualquer(int _x=0, int _y=0, bool algo=false);
    maisUmaFuncaoQualquer(void);
};
```

Quero fazer isso:

```
vetor v(1, 3);
pos p;
p = v;
```

Como faria isso em c++? Precisaria criar uma função para isso, ou estou pensando de maneira errada?

> **Up 1:**

Consegui fazer desta maneira, na classe vetor:

```
class vetor
{
protected:
    int x, y;
public:
    //Construtor
    vetor(int _x=0, int _y=0);

    //Retorna x
    int getX(void);
    //Retorna y
    int getY(void);
};
```

na classe pos:

```
class pos : public vetor
{

public:
    //Construtor default
    pos();
    /*
    Construtor para receber o vetor. É responsável por atribuir a x e y 
    herdados pela classe vetor o x e y de uma instância vetor atribuída, 
    utilizando as funções getX e getY da classe vetor, 
    que pega o x,y que estão protected na mesma.
    Sua implementação:
    pos::pos(vetor _v)
    {
        x = _v.getX();
        y = _v.getY();
    };
    */
    pos(vetor _v);

    umaFuncaoQualquer(int _x=0, int _y=0);
    outraFuncaoQualquer(int _x=0, int _y=0, bool algo=false);
    maisUmaFuncaoQualquer(void);

};
```

com isso o código abaixo funciona:

```
vetor v(1, 3);
pos p;
p = v;
```

Contudo gostaria de conhecer outras maneiras de fazer o mesmo, talvez existam maneiras que se encaixem melhor nesta situação. E não compreendi muito bem porque desta maneira funciona e da primeira não, se ambos possuem x e y. Lembro de ter lido alguma vez sobre isso:

```
//Funciona sem precisar do construtor de cópia
v = p;
//Apenas funciona se tiver um construtor de cópia
p = v;
```

li que é assim, mas não me lembro o porque?

> **Up 2:**

Referente a resposta do @Ossetian_Odin, ainda estou sem entender alguns pontos, vou começar de cima p baixo:

1 - Quanto ao uso de friend, não seria necessário no caso de meu exemplo, pois os membros da classe "vetor" são protected e não private, então já poderão ser acessados pela classe derivada. E o construtor de cópia que o compilador declara, é na própria classe recebendo a própria classe, como quero atribuir uma diferente, exige que eu crie um construtor para isso, o problema é que criei na classe "pos" e não na "vetor", o que fica um tanto confuso, mas não poderia ser o contrario, já que seguindo a lógica "é um", "vetor" não é um "pos", e sim "pos" é um "vetor". Estou certo?

2 - Quanto ao "downcasting", você diz para criar uma classe abstrata, então eu criaria a classe "vetor" como abstrata? Não seria melhor utilizar "dynamic_cast" neste caso? E se eu usar "dynamic_cast" o que acontece quando eu fizer "dynamic_cast < pos * > (&v);", p terá todos as variáveis e funções de "pos"(já que herda "vetor", são as de "vetor" e as que só existem em "pos"), recebendo a atribuição de v as variáveis que possuem em comum, ou p terá apenas o que "vetor" possui?

> **Up 3:**

Dei uma estudada, e percebi que a maneira que fiz no **Up 2** é a certa para este caso, pelo menos a mais certa que encontrei até agora. Pois o que quero fazer é atribuir um objeto "vetor" a um objeto "pos" da maneira mais "abstrata" possível, abstração para outra pessoa que utilizará, é mais fácil fazer "p = v;" do que "static_cast(&vet);" por exemplo; o que preciso não é de um "downcasting", e nem de utilizar polimorfismo, mas agradeço ambas as repostas que me fizeram estudar mais esses conceitos, pois o que realmente é preciso neste caso é simplesmente atribuir "p = v", onde p tendo um construtor para lidar com a classe atribuída funcionará, não é conversão(Polimorfismo) que necessita, e sim uma cópia. Dei uma lida em um material que encontrei no google, e no capitulo "Conversão de ponteiros" me esclareceu:

https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/ftp_pub/lfm/CppBorgesClinio.pdf

Traduzindo para as variáveis da questão:

```
 vetor v, *pv; // pv pode apontar para objetos do tipo vetor e derivados
 pos p, *pp; // pp pode apontar para objetos do tipo pos e derivados

 v = p; // copia v parte vetor de p para v (não é conversão)
 p = v; /* erro! v pode não ter todos elementos para a cópia(A questão se 
           refere a este caso, que também não é conversão, e pode ser 
           resolvido da maneira do Up 2, o que queria saber era se existe
           outras maneiras alem da que fiz no Up 2, que seria para cópia, 
           e não mudança de forma ou tratar um classe como uma 
           diferente)
        */

 pv = &v; // ok
 pv = &p; // ok, pv aponta para um objeto do tipo pos
 pp = pv; // erro! pv pode apontar para um objeto do tipo vetor
 pp = &p; // ok
 pp = &v; // erro! pp não pode apontar para objetos do tipo vetor
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando tratar um objeto da classe mãe como sendo um objeto da classe filha. Isso não funciona.

### Exemplo concreto

Imagine que você tenha as classes `animal`, `gato` (que herda de animal) e `urocordato`. Um `animal` possui o método `comer`. Um `gato` possui também os métodos `miau`, `serFofo` e `ignorarDono`. Um `urocordato` tem também os métodos `metamorfose`, `filtrar` e `brotamento`.

Imagine que para o seu algoritmo você precisa de um `animal`, vamos chamar esse animal de `estimacao`:

```
animal estimacao;
estimacao = new gato();
// faz trabalho com um animal do tipo gato
estimacao = new urocordato();
// faz trabalho com animal do tipo urocordato
```

Não tem problema nenhum o algoritmo acima. Agora, imagine que tenhamos uma função que recebe um `gato` como argumento. Vamos chamar essa função de `mimar`, sua assinatura é `void mimar(gato xano);`. Veja o que acontece abaixo:

```
//declaração e objeto do tipo gato, tudo certo
gato xaninho = new gato();
mimar(xaninho);

// declaração de animal, objeto gato; possível atribuir, mas não possível chamar 'mimar'
animal bixo = new gato();
mimar(bixo);

// declaração de gato, objeto urocordato; impossível atribuir
gato xaninho = new urocordato();
mimar(xaninho);
```

### Por que disso?

Quando você trabalha com herança, você pode assumir que `urocordato` e `gato` podem ser tratados como animais. A definição das classes fala exatamente isso através da herança:

- classe `gato` deriva da classe `animal`: significa que `gato` é um tipo específico de `animal`
- classe `urocordato` deriva da classe `animal`: significa que `urocordato` é um tipo específico de `animal`

Porém você não pode tratar um `animal` genérico como um `gato`. Quando você faz `gato xaninho = new urocordato();` você está tentando tratar um `animal` qualquer como um `gato`.

Se fosse possível tratar um `animal` qualquer como um `gato`, seria possível chamar o método `miau()` de um `urocordato` (por exemplo, na implementação de `void mimar(gato xano)`), sendo que `urocordato`s não são capazes de fazer `miau()`.

> UPDATE

### Construção automática

Se em algum momento, você declarar um construtor da classe com apenas um único objeto argumento, você poderá fazer a atribuição do argumento para a variável daquela classe. Internamente, o C++ vai criar um objeto da classe alvo automaticamente, chamando o construtor adequado. Isso não tem nada a ver com herança.

Exemplo sem usar relação entre `gato` e `animal`:

```
int giid = 0;

class animal {
public:
    int id;
    int iid;
    animal(int _id = 0) {
        cout << "construindo um animal..." << endl;
        id = _id;
        iid = giid++;
    }

};

class gato {
public:
    int id, iid;
    gato(animal a) {
        id = a.id;
        iid = giid++;
        cout << "construtor chamado automaticamente, meaw" << endl;
    }
};

//códigos...
animal a;
gato xano = a; // chama o construtor de gato passando um animal

cout << "instance id do animal " << a.iid << endl;
cout << "instance id do xano " << xano.iid << endl;
//códigos...
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/TQdZNH).

Saída da execução:

> construindo um animal...
>   construtor chamado automaticamente, meaw
>   instance id do animal 0
>   instance id do xano 1

Também montei um outro exemplo que, este sim, fazia a confusão:

```
int giid = 0;

class animal {
public:
int id;
int iid;
animal(int _id = 0) {
cout << "construindo um animal..." << endl;
id = _id;
iid = giid++;
}

};

class gato: public animal {
public:
gato(animal a) {
id = a.id;
cout << "construtor chamado automaticamente, meaw" << endl;
}
};

// códigos...
animal a;
gato xano = a;

cout << "instance id do animal " << a.iid << endl;
cout << "instance id do xano " << xano.iid << endl;
// códigos...
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/ir5d46)

Saída da execução:

> construindo um animal...
>   construindo um animal...
>   construtor chamado automaticamente, meaw
>   instance id do animal 0
>   instance id do xano 1

Comment: E porque quando eu crio um construtor funciona, também não estaria atribuindo?

Comment: Tem como por um trecho de código com a dúvida? Tipo `gato xaninho = new urocordato()`?

Comment: Está na pergunta um exemplo do construtor, no Up 1.

Comment: Mas o que estava perguntando utilizando de seu exemplo serial algo assim: porque `animal bixo = new gato();` funciona em C++, mas `gato gatinho = new animal();` não funciona? mas funciona se eu criar um construtor de copia para lidar com os membros de "animal" e atribui-los ao membros de "gato"?

Comment: @PerduGames vou estudar antes de atualizar a resposta. Parece que seu criar um construtor que recebe um objeto e tentar atribuir esse objeto para o seu, ele sabe como fazer a coerção

Comment: Isso acho que se chama construtor de cópia, mas nunca entendi muito bem como C++ lida com isso.

Comment: @PerduGames, construtor de cópia eu lembro em outro escopo, mas enfim. Fiz o exemplo: http://ideone.com/ir5d46. Vou atualizar minha resposta

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi qual o objetivo/lógica do seu código. Acho que o que você quer fazer se chama "downcasting", que só é possível através de ponteiros e referências:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class vetor
{
protected:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;

public:
    vetor(int x = 0, int y = 0)
    {
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
    }

    void imprime()
    {
        cout << "imprimindo como \'vetor\'";
        cout << "\nx: " << m_x;
        cout << "\ny: " << m_y << "\n\n";
     }
};


class pos : public vetor
{
public:
    pos(int x, int y) : vetor(x, y) {} //chama o construtor da classe base

    void imprime()
    {
        cout << "imprimindo como \'pos\'";
        cout << "\nx: " << m_x;
        cout << "\ny: " << m_y << "\n\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    vetor vet(10, 20);
    vet.imprime();

    pos* ps = static_cast<pos*>(&vet);
    ps->imprime();

    return 0;
}
```

No entanto, usar um ponteiro/referência de uma classe derivada pra um objeto base não é uma boa prática de programação, porque só irá funcionar se o layout das classe base e derivada forem iguais além de deixar o seu programa com uma lógica confusa, quebrando a hierarquia de classes. E também não iria funcionar se você estivesse usando funções virtuais.

O certo seria você criar uma classe base abstrata e usa-la pra referenciar os objetos derivados, usando a lógica "é um", a que o @Jefferson Quesado explicou:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;


class Poligono //classe abstrata
{
public:
    virtual void desenha() = 0; //função virtual pura
    virtual ~Poligono() {} //destrutor é declarado virtual para que seja chamado quando objeto 
     //filho for destruído
};


class Triangulo : public Poligono
{
public:
    void desenha() override //implementa função virtual
    {
        cout << "Desenha triangulo.\n";
    }
};


class Retangulo : public Poligono
{
public:
    void desenha() override
    {
        cout << "Desenha retangulo.\n";
    }
};


void FacaAlgumaCoisa(Poligono& pol)
{
    pol.desenha();
}


int main()
{
    unique_ptr<Poligono> pol; //ponteiro da classe base abstrata

    pol = make_unique<Triangulo>(); //usa pol como triângulo
    pol->desenha();

    pol = make_unique<Retangulo>(); //destroi triângulo e usa pol como retângulo
    pol->desenha();

    //usa uma função para obter o mesmo efeito acima
    FacaAlgumaCoisa(Retangulo());
    FacaAlgumaCoisa(Triangulo());

    return 0;
}
```

Sobre o construtor de cópia, é o construtor que você define para determinar o comportamento da sua classe quando ela é atribuída:

```
class Pessoa
{
    string nome;
    int idade;

public:
    //construtor pra inicializar
    Pessoa(const string& nome, int idade)
    {
        this->nome = nome;
        this->idade = idade;
    }

    //construtor de cópia
    Pessoa(const Pessoa& p)
    {
        cout << p.nome << " esta sendo copiado(a)!\n";
        nome = p.nome; //se os objetos fore do mesmo tipo, vc pode acessar os membro privados
        idade = p.idade;
    }
};
```

Usando a classe:

```
Pessoa p1("John", 30);
Pessoa p2 = p1; //chama o construtor de cópia
Pessoa p3(p1); //faz a mesma coisa que a linha acima
```

Você também pode usar o construtor de cópia de uma classe para receber outro tipo de objeto(tal como você fez, por isso o seu código funcionou quando você atribuiu duas classes de tipos diferentes), mas salvo me engano, você precisará marcar a classe como "amiga" do outro objeto com a keyword [`friend`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class), caso as duas classes nao tenham nenhuma relação. E outro detalhe é que se você não declarar o construtor de cópia, o compilador irá declarar um para o mesmo tipo implicitamente, e o comportamento padrão dele é chamar o operador de atribuição em todos os membros da sua classe.

EDIT:

Respondendo as outras dúvidas:

1 - No caso do seu código, não precisa declarar como friend porque a classe derivada tem acesso aos campos protected da classe base. E não, o compilador gera o construtor de cópia implicitamente em todas as classes que você não declara-lo e implementa-lo. Quando você chama o construtor de cópia, obviamente o construtor default da classe base também é chamado. Eu recomendo que você crie uma classe base e uma derivada e faça testes marcando todos os construtores com `std::cout` pra você entender melhor o funcionamento:

```
struct Base
{
    Base()
    {
        cout << "base created!\n";
    }

    Base(const Base& b)
    {
        cout << "copy constructor base\n";
    }
};

struct Child : Base
{
    Child()
    {
        cout << "child created!\n";
    }

    Child(const Child& c)
    {
        cout << "copy constructor child\n";
    }
};
```

2 - "Downcasting" é quando você tenta usar uma classe derivada como se fosse uma classe base, o que é o oposto do segundo exemplo que eu mostrei. A classe base deveria ser usada como ponteiro/referência, já que as derivadas herdam todas as características da base, e o oposto não ocorre. E sim, "vetor" deveria ser abstrata, mas nesse caso funciona porque ela é idêntica à classe "pos". E `dynamic_cast` serve para o mesmo propósito que um `static_cast` normal, a diferença é que esse cast verifica em tempo de execução se a conversão é válida e retorna um ponteiro nulo caso seja inválida, e só funciona com classes com métodos marcados como `virtual`. No primeiro exemplo do meu post, se você tentasse marcar o método "imprime" como virtual, e substituísse `static_cast` pelo `dynamic_cast`, a conversão falharia pelos motivos que eu já citei(e também porque funções virtuais funcionam de uma forma diferente de métodos comuns). Pesquise sobre hierarquia de classes e polimorfismo, para entender melhor esses conceitos.

Comment: Editei a pergunta "Up 2", estava muito grande para comentar aqui.

Comment: Quando disse "na própria classe", tava me referindo a isso  "Base(const Base& b)", o compilador faz isso implicitamente, não isso "Base(const Child& c)" que é o que acho que quero, digo acho, porque posso está querendo algo de maneira errada, mas o que realmente quero é só que quando eu atribuir um objeto "vetor" a um "pos", que ele pegue os membros em comum(x,y, pois "pos" tem x,y herdado de "vetor" que tem x,y, e essas duas classe seriam diferentes, apenas tendo esses membros em comum) e faça a atribuição.